# iOS, JavaScript - Swift bridge

Tags: ios, swift, bridge

Есть ли возможность в swift внедрить в WebView свой класс, который будет доступен из JavaScript (как на андроиде или как на Qt)?

Comment: можно обмениваться сообщениями, так делает cordova и подобные ей библиотеки, навскидку не вспомню, но там один js файл, который не так трудно разобрать как работает

Comment: Через свою схему url  -  да, знаю, но это сильно отличается от подхода в андроиде и Qt. Если тут так никак, придется обертку на JS писать...

Comment: Ну и вариант со схемой не подходит, по причине - а как возвращаемое значение получить? Надо что-то типа res = obj.method(params);  где obj это "внедренный" объект который будет что-то нативно делать по каждому методу, и резльтат возвращать.
Или яблоки как всегда впереди планеты всей со своим "ничего иззя"

Comment: Александр, рекомендую обратить внимание на мой комментарий, найдите любую статью про то как работает cordova.

Comment: Роберт, я ее посмотрел. На первый взгляд это какой-то монстр, которого надо установить и чутьли не вместо штатного компилятора использовать.. Так понял что Cordova = PhoneGap.

Comment: Есть "новый план".. сделать через синхроные AJAX запросы, перехватывая их в WebView. Такое возможно? Кастомную схему же вот можно перехватить, т.о. передать сообщение из JS в Swift, а можно ли при этом вернуть свой документ? (т.е. как будто AJAX обратился на сервер и получил документ).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, до финта ушами с ajax не дошло. Нашел вот такое решение. Не идеал, но меня пока устроило. Может кому еще пригодится.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview

Comment: Да, я говорил про первый метод обмена сообщениями, смысл cordova сводится к одному вызову.